# adding style for the text tag in svg elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have a graph dynamically created so the svg contains a part with the following code.
bt im unable to give background-color to this class.. ive tried it dynamically with the attr() function, but it doesnt work that way..
is there anyway to specify the css like svg:text??

```
<text id="circleText_Persons-bruno-waterfield" font-size="14" class="circleText" font-family="Tahoma" text-anchor="middle" background-color="#000000" font-weight="900" display="block" x="-1.8714285714285717" y="28.711414285714287" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" style="fill: #666666;">Bruno Waterfield</text>
```

dynamic creation of svg text

```
      nodeEnter.append("svg:text") 
  .attr("id", function(d){  return "circleText_" + d.name})
      .attr("font-size", function(d){return 14;}) //returnNodeSize(d) / 2
      .attr("class",  function(d){return "circleText"}).attr("font-family", "Tahoma")
      .attr("text-anchor","middle")
      .attr("background-color","#000000")
      .attr("font-weight","900")
      //returnNodeSize(d)+returnNodeSize(d)/1.8;
       .text(function(d){ 

         return toTitleCase(d.name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a `rect` of your chosen color behind the `text` element conforming to the bounding box of the text. SVG text does not have a flow box with which to set the background color; you have to make one.

Comment: ive edited the question... so if i add a rectangle will it work like svg:rect:text

Comment: @SamDaSilva No, you need to generate the `svg:rect` and put it just before the text element, then set its x, y, width, and height to be the same as the following text element (once you know these values).